# python setuptools: "No module named version"

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools

I'm trying to install a package using `python setup.py build`, but it fails when it cannot find `setuptools.version`.  In fact:

```
import setuptools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/gpajer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site- packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    import setuptools.version
ImportError: No module named version
```

Shouldn't there be a file `.../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/version.py`? There is no such file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From https://anaconda.org/anaconda/setuptools:

> To install this package with conda run:

```
conda install -c anaconda setuptools=21.2.1
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint ... but no joy.

Comment: have you tried pip? http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/pkgs.html#install-non-conda-packages